# Meaning of Azure CLI status codes with extension for bot

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-deployment, azure-bot-service

I'm running the following Azure CLI command to display changes in a bot.

```
az bot publish --resource-group botxxx --name latest-xxxx --debug -o json
```

The fact is that it returns the next output. I have searched but I can't find where they explain the meaning of the status codes. In my case, "status": 4.

```
Event: CommandInvoker.OnFilterResult []
{
  "active": true,
  "author": "N/A",
  "author_email": "N/A",
  "complete": true,
  "deployer": "Push-Deployer",
  "end_time": "2018-09-17T08:11:59.6100459Z",
  "id": "3fc9899xxxxxxxxxxa06b0ab4d7e5",
  "is_readonly": true,
  "is_temp": false,
  "last_success_end_time": "2018-09-17T08:11:59.6100459Z",
  "log_url": "https://latest-xxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log",
  "message": "Created via a push deployment",
  "progress": "",
  "received_time": "2018-09-17T08:11:56.9780509Z",
  "site_name": "latest-xxxx",
  "start_time": "2018-09-17T08:11:57.1968236Z",
  "status": 4,
  "status_text": "",
  "url": "https://latest-xxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest"
}
Event: Cli.PostExecute []
```

My Azure CLI versions if needed:

```
C:\Users\hlorenzo\Desktop\latest-src>az --version
azure-cli (2.0.44)
```

I have searched the official documentation and found no solution. Thank you very much for the help.